# nvidia drivers (455) installed? but not working

Tags: 18.04, drivers, cuda

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii libnvidia-cfg1-455:amd64 455.32.00-0ubuntu1 amd64 NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii libnvidia-common-455 455.32.00-0ubuntu1 all Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii libnvidia-compute-455:amd64 455.32.00-0ubuntu1 amd64 NVIDIA libcompute package
ii libnvidia-decode-455:amd64 455.32.00-0ubuntu1 amd64 NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii libnvidia-encode-455:amd64 455.32.00-0ubuntu1 amd64 NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii libnvidia-extra-455:amd64 455.32.00-0ubuntu1 amd64 Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii libnvidia-fbc1-455:amd64 455.32.00-0ubuntu1 amd64 NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii libnvidia-gl-455:amd64 455.32.00-0ubuntu1 amd64 NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii libnvidia-ifr1-455:amd64 455.32.00-0ubuntu1 amd64 NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii nvidia-compute-utils-455 455.32.00-0ubuntu1 amd64 NVIDIA compute utilities
ii nvidia-dkms-455 455.32.00-0ubuntu1 amd64 NVIDIA DKMS package
ii nvidia-driver-455 455.32.00-0ubuntu1 amd64 NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii nvidia-kernel-common-455 455.32.00-0ubuntu1 amd64 Shared files used with the kernel module
ii nvidia-kernel-source-455 455.32.00-0ubuntu1 amd64 NVIDIA kernel source package
ii nvidia-modprobe 455.32.00-0ubuntu1 amd64 Load the NVIDIA kernel driver and create device files
ii nvidia-prime 0.8.8.2 all Tools to enable NVIDIA’s Prime
ii nvidia-settings 455.32.00-0ubuntu1 amd64 Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii nvidia-utils-455 455.32.00-0ubuntu1 amd64 NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-455 455.32.00-0ubuntu1 amd64 NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

and

```
nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA ® Cuda compiler driver
Copyright © 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Sep_15_19:10:02_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.1, V11.1.74
Build cuda_11.1.TC455_06.29069683_0
```

but

```
nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn’t communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

the nvidia bug report starts off with a bunch of failed conftests:
 #error acpi_walk_namespace() conftest failed!
     ^
   /tmp/selfgz20040/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/conftest/functions.h:64:2: error: #error wait_on_bit_lock() conftest failed!
    #error wait_on_bit_lock() conftest failed!
     ^
   /tmp/selfgz20040/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/conftest/functions.h:69:2: error: #error radix_tree_replace_slot() conftest failed!
    #error radix_tree_replace_slot() conftest failed!

and then finishes with general errors:
./arch/x86/include/asm/bug.h:35:22: error: expected identifier or '(' before string constant
  asm_inline volatile("1:\t" ins "\n"
```

also:

```
gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.5.0-12ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.5.0 20171010 (Ubuntu 5.5.0-12ubuntu1)
```

sudo lshw -C video
`[sudo] password for iviti:  *-display UNCLAIMED        description: VGA compatible controller product: GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] vendor: NVIDIA Corporation physical id: 0 bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0 version: a1 width: 64 bits clock: 33MHz capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list configuration: latency=0 resources: memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a4080000-a40fffff *-display description: VGA compatible controller product: Intel Corporation vendor: Intel Corporation physical id: 2 bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0 version: 00 width: 64 bits clock: 33MHz capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom configuration: driver=i915 latency=0 resources: irq:158 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff`

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1287997/edit) your question and add more details about your computer that you have Ubuntu installed on?  Also, can you add the output of `sudo lshw -C video`?  More details can help us help you!  Thank you!

Comment: What is the recommended driver? (`ubuntu-drivers devices` from `sudo apt install ubnutu-drivers-common`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my guess:  You replaced the default gcc compiler (8.4?) with version 5.5, and big surprise, the Nvidia driver no longer compiles successfully.
Assuming you actually need Nvidia driver 455 (not yet offered from standard Ubuntu repositories), and the driver build actually works on Ubuntu, undo the alternatives on the gcc, use links named gcc, g++, ar, ranlib etc. to the old versions in your ...CUDA/bin directory (which should be first in your PATH).
With the system gcc at the correct version, at least the Nvidia driver should be able to work.

---

For overriding the gcc used for CUDA work, without changing what the system uses for updates to things like the video module, see
[steps to run the cuda sample program for vector addition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896351/steps-to-run-the-cuda-sample-program-for-vector-addition/1265892#1265892)
Here's a cut of the relevant paragraph:

First read the Ubuntu sections on your CUDA Installation Guide: e.g. https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.nvidia.com%2Fcuda%2Fpdf%2FCUDA_Installation_Guide_Linux.pdf&pdf=true

The recommendations in chapter 6 on setting the environment variables PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH indicate your cuda additions should be at the beginning of the existing PATH. This allows you to override the system g++ or gcc with an older version by simply adding links to the ...cuda/bin to the version you want. The last thing you want to do is change a system default compiler -- one which may not successfully be able to update your video driver when a kernel update occurs. If everything you do may use the old compiler, go ahead and modify your PATH setup in your .profile, so every login your cuda path gets set up. If you only want your CUDA work to use the old compiler, put the PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH modifications into a script to source when you want to.

Comment: gcc 5.5 was what my computer thought the default was (sudo apt install gcc). I ended up doing a general update to ubuntu (up to Focal Fossa). When I tried reinstalling cuda/nvidia everything worked the first time. I think my Ubuntu was screwed up in general

Comment: @ubfan1, can you please add a little detail of how to downgrade gcc compiler for this driver version 4.55 to work?